# Cannot accept post in Sinatra using Curl

Tags: ruby, rest, post, curl, sinatra

Just been tinkering with Sinatra and trying to get a bit of a restful web service going.
The error I'm getting at the moment is very specific though.

Take this example post method

```
post '/postMan/:someParam' do
    #Edited here. This code can be anything. 411 is still the response
    puts params[:someParam]

end
```

Seems simple enough. Take a param, make an object out of it, then go store it in whatever way the objects save method defines.

Heres what I use to post the data using Curl

```
$curl -I -X POST http://127.0.0.1/postman/123456
```

The only problem is, I'm getting 411 back and have no idea why.
To the best of my knowledge, 411 is length required. Here is the trace

```
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
Date: Fri, 02 Mar 2012 22:27:09 GMT
Content-Length: 303
Connection: close
```

I 'Cannot' change the curl message in any way. So might anyone have a way to set the content length to be ignored in sinatra? Or some fix which doesn't involve changing the curl request?

---

For the record, it doesn't matter whether I use the parameters in the Post method or not. I could have some crazy code inside it, it  will still throw the same error

Comment: When you actually post data (e.g. with `-d key=val`) do you get the same result?

Comment: @nategood I'm not familiar with curl too much. If this is correct 'curl -d key=val http://127.0.0.1:4567/postman/123456' Then the response is the default sinatra 404 (AKA sinatra doesn't know this ditty)

Comment: Try `curl -I -X POST -d "key=val" http://127.0.0.1/postman/123456`

Comment: @nategood response is ""Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!"", sorry but thats probably something I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're on port 80 for your app? 
When I run:

```
ruby -r sinatra -e "post('/postMan/:someParam'){puts params[:someParam]}"
```

and curl it:

```
curl -I -X POST http://127.0.0.1:4567/postMan/123456                                                                            
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: thin 1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso
```

it's ok. Had to change the URL to `postMan`though, your example threw a `404`because you had `postman`.

The output was also as expected:

```
== Sinatra/1.3.2 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
123456
```

Comment: I think its running on a default of port :4567. I've tried your way but perhaps it has got something to do with my sinatra setup. One thing, I'm using webrick, not thin

Comment: BY GOD YOU'VE DONE IT!!!! I switched from webrick to thin. All of a sudden, it starts working. maybe webrick doesn't account for content length. Thanks so much!

Comment: thin is default in newer sinatra versions. I'd never think about using webrick. It's like the slowest player on the field. Use thin or puma!

Answer (score 5):

As others said above, WEBrick wrongly requires POST requests to have a Content-Length header. I just pass an empty body, because it's less typing than passing in the header:

```
curl -X POST -d '' http://webrickwhyyounotakeemptyposts.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah.  Try it without `-I`.  It's probably sending a `HEAD` request and as such, not sending what you expect.  Use `-v` if you want to show the headers.

```
curl -v -X POST http://127.0.0.1/postman/123456

curl -v -X POST -d "key=val" http://127.0.0.1/postman/123456
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. The output of the request is here. It's still giving a 411. http://pastebin.com/t9rumPAu  Bare in mind, that in the final version. I cannot change the curl command.

Answer (score 1):

WEBrick erroneously requires POST requests to include the `Content-Length` header.

```
curl -H 'Content-Length: 0' -X POST http://example.com
```

Standardly, however, [POST requests don't require a body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233372/is-an-http-put-request-required-to-include-a-body) and therefore don't require the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: I have same issue with PUT request