# Mongoose: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node.js, so I have a feeling that this will be something silly that I have overlooked, but I haven't been able to find an answer that fixes my problem. What I'm trying to do is create a path that will create a new child object, add it to the parent's array of children, then return the child object to the requester. The problem that I am running into is that if I pass the string id into findById, node crashes with

> TypeError: Object {} has no method 'cast'

If I try to pass in an ObjectId instead, I get

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"

Here is a rough outline of my code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId; //Have also tried Schema.Types.ObjectId, mongoose.ObjectId

mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@server:port/database');

app.get('/myClass/:Id/childClass/create', function(request, result) {
  var id = new ObjectId(request.params.Id);
  MyClass.findById(id).exec( function(err, myClass) {
    if (err || !myClass) { result.send("error: " + err + "<br>" + JSON.stringify(id) || ("object '" + request.params.Id + "' not found: " + id)); return; }
    var child = ChildClass();
    myClass.Children.addToSet(child);
    myClass.save();
    result.send(child);
  });
});
```

If I execute this code with the path "/myClass/51c35e5ced18cb901d000001/childClass/create", this is the output of the code:

> error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"
>   {"path":"51c35e5ced18cb901d000001","instance":"ObjectID","validators":[],"setters":[],"getters":[],"_index":null}

I've tried using findOne and passing in {_id:id} instead, but this appears to be exactly what findById does. I've tried the different classes for ObjectId that I've seen listed on other sites. I've tried calling ObjectId() like a function instead of a constructor and that returns undefined. At this point, I'm running out of ideas and it doesn't seem that googling for an answer is helping. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Also, like I said, I'm new to node/Mongo/Mongoose/Express, so if there is a better way to accomplish my goal, please let me know. I appreciate all feedback.

**EDIT:**

After the workaround from Peter Lyons, I googled another error that I was running into and found findByIdAndUpdate, which works as expected and does exactly what I was hoping to do. I'm still not sure why findById and findOne were giving me such issues and I'm curious to know (maybe a bug report needs to be filed), so I'll leave this open in case someone else has an answer.

Comment: My guess is your were calling `findOne` with a single `ObjectId` but `findOne` expects a regular JS Object of key/value conditions.

Comment: I have answered these question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567319/getting-error-in-mongodb-cast-issue-for-valid-object-id/53139672#53139672).

Comment: Check your routes. It might be that two routes have the same starting point example "#GET /user/:userID and #GET /user/list". The route will use "list" as an input to the database and will give some error.

Answer (score 93):

Short answer: use **mongoose.Types.ObjectId**.

Mongoose (but not mongo) can accept object Ids as strings and "cast" them properly for you, so just use:

```
MyClass.findById(req.params.id)
```

However, the caveat is if `req.params.id` is not a valid format for a mongo ID string, that will throw an exception which you must catch.

So the main confusing thing to understand is that `mongoose.SchemaTypes` has stuff you only use when defining mongoose schemas, and `mongoose.Types` has the stuff you use when creating data objects you want to store in the database or query objects. So `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("51bb793aca2ab77a3200000d")` works, will give you an object you can store in the database or use in queries, and will throw an exception if given an invalid ID string.

`findOne` takes a query object and passes a single model instance to the callback. And `findById` is literally a wrapper of `findOne({_id: id})` ([see source code here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L883)). Just `find` takes a query object and passes an array of matching model instances to the callback.

Just go slow. It's confusing but I can guarantee you you are getting confused and not hitting bugs in mongoose at this point. It's a pretty mature library, but it takes some time to get the hang of it.

The other suspect thing I see in your snippet is not using `new` when instantiating `ChildClass`. Beyond that, you'll need to post your schema code in order for us to help you tract down any CastErrors that remain.

Comment: If I try to use "mongoose.Types.ObjectId("51c35e5ced18cb901d000001");" (by placing it directly in code), I still get the error "TypeError: Object {} has no method 'cast'". I also tried instantiating it as an object and got the same error.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest mongoose? I'm on 3.6.11.

Comment: Calling MyClass.find(req.params.id) works. Shouldn't findOne and findById work the same way? It just seems a bit counter-intuitive to have find be the function that returns a single document when the other two exist. I've altered the code to get the first item of the array now, but it is failing on addToSet() now with "TypeError: Object {} has no method 'cast'".

Comment: I'm also on 3.6.11. I just set all of this up the other night, so I'd expect that everything is already up to date.

Comment: Does not work as of July 3 2014!! Why `new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId("51bb793aca2ab77a3200000d")` works fine, but `new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId(request.params[0])` throws an error?? Whereby I place a string `"51bb793aca2ab77a3200000d"` in a url `/51bb793aca2ab77a3200000d`. And when obtained from a url it throws an error.

Comment: You are using the wrong constructor function. Use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. `mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` is for defining schemas only.

Answer (score 60):

I've faced this error, That was because the value you want to filter in the _id field is not in an ID format, one "if" should solve your error.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('53cb6b9b4f4ddef1ad47f943'));
// true
console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('whatever'));
// false
```

To solve it, always validate if the criteria value for search is a valid ObjectId

```
const criteria = {};
criteria.$or = [];

if(params.q) {
  if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(params.id)) {
    criteria.$or.push({ _id: params.q })
  }
  criteria.$or.push({ name: { $regex: params.q, $options: 'i' }})
  criteria.$or.push({ email: { $regex: params.q, $options: 'i' }})
  criteria.$or.push({ password: { $regex: params.q, $options: 'i' }})
}

return UserModule.find(criteria).exec(() => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Comment: Correct. I was testing an endpoint to `GET` user with a `findById`, turns out that the id param must be 12 bits, otherwise mongoose will fail to cast. I was using random short numbers.

Answer (score 5):

For all those people stuck with this problem, but still couldn't solve it: I stumbled upon the same error and found the `_id` field being empty.

I described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268793/mongoose-findone-method-retrieves-valid-document-with-missing-id/28269209#28269209) in more detail. Still have not found a solution except changing the fields in `_id` to not-ID fields which is a dirty hack to me. I'm probably going to file a bug report for mongoose. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I updated my thread. I filed a ticket and they confirmed the missing `_id` problem. It is going to be fixed in the 4.x.x version which has a release candidate available right now. The rc is not recommended for productive use!

Comment: interesting, I think I have the same problem, my _id was undefined and therefore could not be cast to ObjectId

Answer (score 4):

If you are having this issue and you are performing a populate somewhere along the lines, [see this Mongoose issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2729).

Update to Mongoose 4.0 and the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, I just coerced the id into a string.

My schema:

```
const product = new mongooseClient.Schema({
    retailerID: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, required: true, index: true }
});
```

And then, when inserting:

```
retailerID: `${retailer._id}`
```

Answer (score 2):

I want data from all docs, and I don't want `_id`, so I do:

```
User.find({}, {_id:0, keyToShow:1, keyToNotShow:0})
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, turned out after I have updated my schema, I have forgotten I was calling the model using the old id, which was created by me; I have updated my schema from something like:

```
patientid: {
           type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
          },
```

to

```
patientid: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: "Patient" },
```

It turned out, since my code is big, I was calling the `findOne` with the old id, therefore, the problem.

I am posting here just to help somebody else: please, **check your code for unknown wrong calls**! it may be the problem, and it can save your huge headacles!

Comment: Hi there! This one was the solution to my problem too! I had to insert new data on the new model for it work. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this error  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “[object Object]” at path “_id” after creating a schema, then modifying it and couldn't track it down. I deleted all the documents in the collection and I could add 1 object but not a second. I ended up deleting the collection in Mongo and that worked as Mongoose recreated the collection.

Answer (score 1):

For the record: I had this error trying to fill a subdocument in a wrong way:

```
{
[CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"]
message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"',
name: 'CastError',
type: 'ObjectId',
path: '_id'
value:
  [ { timestamp: '2014-07-03T00:23:45-04:00',
  date_start: '2014-07-03T00:23:45-04:00',
  date_end: '2014-07-03T00:23:45-04:00',
  operation: 'Deactivation' } ],
}
```

look ^ value is an array containing an object: wrong!

Explanation: I was sending data from php to a node.js API in this way:

```
$history = json_encode(
array(
  array(
  'timestamp'  => date('c', time()),
  'date_start' => date('c', time()),
  'date_end'   => date('c', time()),
  'operation'  => 'Deactivation'
)));
```

As you can see $history is an array containing an array. That's why mongoose try to fill _id (or any other field) with an array instead than a Scheme.ObjectId (or any other data type). The following works:

```
$history = json_encode(
array(
  'timestamp'  => date('c', time()),
  'date_start' => date('c', time()),
  'date_end'   => date('c', time()),
  'operation'  => 'Deactivation'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this mongoose error

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"583fe2c488cf652d4c6b45d1\" at path \"_id\" for model User
```

So I run npm list command to verify the mongodb and mongoose version in my local.
Heres the report:

```
......  
......  
├── mongodb@2.2.19  
├── mongoose@4.7.2  
.....
```

It seems there's an issue on this mongodb version so what I did is I uninstall and try to use different version such as 2.2.16

`$ npm uninstall mongodb`, it will delete the mongodb from your node_modules directory. After that install the lower version of mongodb.
`$ npm install mongodb@2.2.16`
Finally, I restart the app and the CastError is gone!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will help but I resolved the issue by importing mongoose like below and implementing it as below

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
```

Answer (score 1):

so in my case , i used the put request from a doc and i request to api file
and what i did is i send the "id" wrongly through the url
this was mistake
"/api/posts/${postId}/like"  but changing the double quotations to backticks changed the game ,`/api/posts/${postId}/like`  and in the api file when i use the findbyid(postid) , i got the resut without error

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.Turns out my Node.js was outdated. After upgrading it's working.

Answer (score 0):

just change the path it will work for example

```
app.get('/myClass/:Id/childClass/create', function(request, result) .....
```

change to

```
app.get('/myClass**es**/:Id/childClass/create', function(request, result) .....
```

I just added --es-- to the path (myClass) to become (myClasses)

now should work and will not see that error

Answer (score 0):

For me, the ID was undefined (req.params.id returns undefined)

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding a document by its "_id" for a model, say Drivers, the command below works quite well:

```
....
const driver = await Drivers.findById(<your id>);
....
```

Ensure you use the async-await and try-catch ES6 syntax

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using a put request without sending any data. I changed it to a post request and it worked.

[This thread covers more about put requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233372/is-an-http-put-request-required-to-include-a-body)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
MyClass.findOne(id)
```

Instead of:

```
MyClass.findById(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
userRouter.get("/:id/:walletAddress", getDefaultWallet);
userRouter.get("/filterUser/:name", filterUserListByName);
```

First, I was using this, I got the above error then
I change the position it works for me. Keep all routers above to "/: id/XYZ"

```
userRouter.get("/filterUser/:name", filterUserListByName);
userRouter.get("/:id/:walletAddress", getDefaultWallet);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34427490)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the exact `GET` requests sent by the browser.

For me the cause of this error was some `dummy_image` data in the DB for an image. Using that in an `<img>` tag as `src="dummy_image"` caused the browser to send a `GET` request to `/dummy_image` which was caught by the `.get("/:id")` route and the string `"dummy_image"` was queried as the value of `id`.