# Mongoose findOne method retrieves valid document with missing _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently on a very weird mongoose error and I don't know what is causing this problem. When I call `findOne` method, I get a valid instance, with only the `_id` field not initialized. When I'm trying to save the changes in that document it crashes with

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"]
 message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"',
 name: 'CastError',
 type: 'ObjectId',
 value: 
   { from_node_id: 52e10f6acce9daa7f3bf3162,
     target_id: 'a' },
 path: '_id' }
```

I have a simple Schema Definition:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var transitionProbabilitySchema;
transitionProbabilitySchema = new Schema({
   _id: {
       from_node_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Zone"}
   },
   value: {
       total_transition_count: Number,
       probabilities: [
           {to_node_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Zone"}},
           {probability: Number}
       ]}
}, {collection: 'transitionProbability'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('transitionProbability', transitionProbabilitySchema);
```

and when I now call

```
TransitionProbability.findOne({"_id.from_node_id": from_node_id},
        function (err, tp) {
            if (err) {
                handleError('error - tp not found', err, callback);
            } else {
                 // some modification of tp and then save
            }
        }
```

Mongoose returns the document, but only `_id`is not initialized. The whole function crashes when I am trying to save the altered document and not before. I also logged the document to the console to verify it is just the `_id' field missing.

PS: note, that the `from_node_id` is extracted from another query and is a valid `ObjectId`.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: setting the _id field manually does not seem to work either. Even more interesting: while trying out other methods, I recognized that `findOneAndUpdate`for example does freeze the whole node.js app, without any log. It just doesn't continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: For your information: after searching for two days straight without finding an answer I created a ticket for a possible bug at Mongoose.js Github and they confirmed my problem. [According to them it is fixed in the new 4.0.0 release candidate](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2646), which is not recommended for productive use. At actually solved my problem, but the rc1 made even more problems.

---

My solution so far:

Finally I was so annoyed by this error, that I changed my whole cumulation of that table so that `_id` does not have a separate `from_node_id` field. I use the `from_node_id` now as the ID directly.

Comment: I have a schema that has a subdoc ref that is originally filled with a valid value. I'm able to set the ref value to undefined without issue. But setting a valid value back to the now undefined ref field produces a Cast to ObjectId fail error. Is all of this related? I'm using Mongoose ~3.8.8.

Comment: You're problem seems to be a different one, since you can retrieve documents with filled values. My problem is actually that the _id is not filled with a valid value which makes modifying the retrieved document impossible.

Comment: Yea, it is different. It's related to the fact that I'm attempting to update a populated document via a MEAN.js update scaffold for Express. I'm looking at different ways to work around this, but they're all quite ugly (e.g.: re-query the parent model, and manually fill in the details from the request in the Express controller). I'd have hoped that Mongoose would at least detect this case and provide better feedback.