# Mongoose: TypeError: hex is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a simple data persistence app using mongoose, After getting stuck on this error

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'id' }" at path "_id" for model 'foo'

i tried to use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`  as suggested by various threads, one partcular : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17223701/4206519, but now I am getting a new error:

> TypeError: hex is not a function.

Here is a relevant part of the code:

```
app.get('/campgrounds/:id', function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
    Campground.findById(ObjectId, function(err, found){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //render show template with that campground
            res.render('show.ejs', {campground: found});
        } 
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server has started");
});
```

Being a newbie, i may be making a simple mistake here, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From last 2 days i am also getting the same problem and it's due to the version issue

i was using these version 
"mongodb": "^2.2.19",

"mongoose": "^4.7.6",
and getting the error that Hex is not a function

then i change the version to 
 "mongodb": "2.1.7",
 "mongoose": "4.4.8"

and it start working so i think they have removed the hex function and other so try after installing this version 
in your package.json dont use ^before version name just add 
 "mongodb": "2.1.7",
 "mongoose": "4.4.8"
and install

Comment: This worked for me. We'll have to figure out what's expected if we want to update.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);` and it should work
...And pass the id instead of the ObjectId in the findById function :)

Comment: Initially i was doing just that, but it threw the following error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'id' }" at path "_id" for model 'foo'.

Comment: Okay that is confusing, try: Campground.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, found) { ... });

Comment: I believe both .findOne({_id:id}) and findById(id) are basically same. have tried but no change in the output here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mongodb driver , you can do like

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
var id = new ObjectID(req.params.id); // Hex
```

**Mongoose**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('4edd40c86762e0fb12000003');
var _id = mongoose.mongo.ObjectId("4eb6e7e7e9b7f4194e000001");

console.log(id);
console.log(_id);

//4edd40c86762e0fb12000003
//4eb6e7e7e9b7f4194e000001
```

**How to use in findById**

```
Campground.findById(id.toString(), function (err, found) { 
        // Do Whatever you like after getting data
 } );
```

Comment: It's giving same error: TypeError: hex is not a function