# Getting error in mongodb cast issue for valid object id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My code was working fine but after taking fresh code I am getting this error but as I can see my id is valid **Object Id**

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value "5848e9ecaec0f31372816a26" at path
>   "_id" for model "user"

how to fix this?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Have you tried searching for this error in SO? May be you will find your solution.

Comment: I could not find anywhere then i have added here

Comment: @AshuKashyap Can you add some code to show us where the problem occurs?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue since a few hours.

Comment: After downgrading from `mongoose@4.7.6` to `mongoose@4.6.6` the error is gone.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderZeitler i have downgrade to  "mongoose": "^4.6.5"  , now it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is documented in [this mongoose issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4877).
A workaround is to downgrade to mongoose version <= 4.7.2 or use Node version >=6.

Comment: i have downgrade to "mongoose": "^4.6.5" , now it is working

Answer (score 2):

You have to cast the data to mongodb object id.
If you are using mongoose, you can actually do these below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

[your_mongodb_model/collection].query({ _id: ObjectId(id) });
```

or simply, you can do these,

```
[your_mongodb_model].query({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) });
```