# Mongoose - Schema with nested SchemaId array

Tags: javascript, mongoose, postman

I have a method that creates restaurant:

```
const { restaurant } = req;

        if (!restaurant || !Object.keys(restaurant).length) {
            return { msg: "Not enough data!", status: 500 };
        }
        const restaurantRecord = new Restaurants(restaurant);

        await restaurantRecord.save();
```

It has the following schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Food } = require("./food");

const RestaurantsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, index: true, unique: true, default: "Test queue" },
        menu: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Food, index: true, default: [] }]
    },
    { collection: "restaurants" }
);

module.exports.Restaurants = mongoose.model("Restaurants", RestaurantsSchema);
```

It has an array of Food schemas:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const FoodSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, index: true, unique: true, default: "Some food" },
        price: { type: Number, index: true, default: 100 },
    },
    { collection: "food" }
);

module.exports.Food = mongoose.model("Food", FoodSchema);
```

When I try to create restourant in Postman like this:

```
{
    "restaurant":
    {
        "name": "Test restaurant",
        "menu":
        [
            {"name": "Test food"},
            {"name": "Test food 2"}
        ]
    }
}
```

i get an error:
[image]

How can I fix this? I guess it needs me to create Food object or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the id field.

There is many other post about this error seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223517/mongoose-casterror-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-object-object-at-path)