# How can I specify multiple request types per endpoint in API Blueprint?

Tags: apiblueprint

Is it possible to define what happens when `PUT to /asdf` with an empty request body happens vs `PUT to /asdf` with this request body with `{ "value": "somthing" }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the media type of both requests is the same and the response HTTP status codes differs this should be legit:

```
# PUT /asdf
+ Request Empty (application/json)
    + Headers

            Content-Lenght: 0

+ Response 400

+ Request With Value (application/json)

        { "value": "somthing" }

+ Response 204
```

Comment: Note the first `Request Empty` currently yields a parser warning. I have made an issue for this problem here https://github.com/apiaryio/snowcrash/issues/77. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1233569/634940 for details on PUT and empty body

Comment: In 4.3.1.4.3. Action Request Section, 4.3.1.4.4. Action Response Section is says "exactly one HTTP request/response" then later it says  one or more different (that is with different HTTP Status codes). That's confusing.

Comment: On top of that, I actually was hoping to define who different descriptions both Response 204, one of a request with an empty request body and one with input.

Comment: @JinyoungKim good point on 4.3.1.4.3. I am currently re-structuring the specification as part of https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/59 so I will make sure this get addressed

Comment: In my answer I was commenting on the current situation. For the future it is planned to allow multiple transaction examples (e.g. same response statuses) as a part of the testing support (https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/21)