# Should a RESTful service return the resource if no object was provided during a PUT?

Tags: rest

I have a REST API with a `PUT` endpoint which looks like this:

`api.website.net/resources/resourceId`

The controller implementation of this endpoint looks like follows:

`@RequestMapping("/resources/{resourceId}")
public Resource putResource(@PathVariable(value = "resourceId") String resourceId, @RequestBody(required = false) Resource resource)`

There is the case where a user may perform a `PUT` on this resource, but neglect to provide an object in the body (i.e. `resource == null` is true).

Which of the following approaches is more RESTful?

1. Have a `PUT` on this endpoint simply return the existing `Resource` object with no changes, or
2. Make the object required in the request body?

Note that the object **exists** at the given URL in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my interpretation of the definition of `PUT`, it would be more RESTful to require a body because the definition seems to imply an entity exists:

From https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

> 9.6 PUT
>
> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
>   supplied Request-URI.

The part which says "the enclosed entity" to me implies an entity actually exists.

I think if you `PUT` nothing, it would end up being the same as a `DELETE`. This just makes me think even more that a body should be required for `PUT` and `DELETE` should be used for that functionality.

All this being said, it is certainly possible to implement something which accepts `PUT` requests with no body, though as I said I don't think this would be RESTful.

There is some discussion about this topic here: [Is an HTTP PUT request required to include a body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233372/is-an-http-put-request-required-to-include-a-body)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems indeed the better choice to include the body in every `PUT` request.

Answer (score 1):

> There is the case where a user may perform a PUT on this resource, but neglect to provide an object in the body (i.e. resource == null is true).

Intriguing.

The PUT method is mentioned in [appendix D](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#appendix-D.1.1) of the HTTP/1.0 spec, was included in the [HTTP/1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6), and is currently defined within the [content and semantics chapter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) of the 2014 HTTP/1.1 spec.

Its use case lineage is [page publishing](http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put), taking the representation embedded within the request and writing it into the servers own store.

A PUT request, with no payload, is analogous to a request that you upsert an empty file into a specific location.  That's a perfectly reasonable thing for a file system or a key value store to do.

> Which of the following approaches is more RESTful?

The applicable constraint of REST is the uniform interface - PUT on this resource should have the same semantics as PUT everywhere else on the web.  So it's important that PUT handling is [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), and that a successful PUT [creates/replaces](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) the state of the resource with the state defined by the representation in the request.

> Have a PUT on this endpoint simply return the existing Resource object with no changes
> Make the object required in the request body?

The second of these, I think, is closer to what you want.  You can't force the client to send you a valid representation of your resource, but you can reject any request that doesn't provide a valid representation.  So if you find that the provided representation isn't satisfactory, you should be thinking in terms of [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) or [409 Conflict](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8).

Note: when sending a 4xx response, you are normally sending a representation of the problem, rather than a representation of the resource.

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

Returning a copy of the current state of the resource isn't useful for telling the client what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was a tough choice to choose between the two, I wish I could accept both. :)